# Do I need to dispose IDisposable that have the same lifetime as the application itself?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, idisposable

I have an `IDiposable` object that lives "forever" in the application. In my case that is `SemaphoreSlim`, but the question applies really to any objects that can be disposed.

I know for sure that I need an object for as long as the application runs. So the question is: do I really need to ensure it is disposed or all unmanaged resources are freed anyway when the process ends? (Both Windows and Linux if that matters).

The problem with disposing is that I have my semaphore deep in the stack and theoretically that means that my whole stack of objects has to implement `IDisposable` just because somewhere there is a semaphore that really never needs to get disposed.

I want to avoid but not sure about consequences.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it a waste of time to free resources before I exit a process?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/140483/30872)

Comment: There is no point in releasing the semaphore early when it happens a millisecond later anyway.  The finalizer thread always runs just before program termination.

Comment: @HansPassant So then I don't need to have IDisposable on the whole stack of objects that uses the semaphore?

Comment: You are making it broad, IDisposable does tend to get abused pretty badly.  SemaphoreSlim doesn't abuse it.  But if these objects only implement IDisposable to release that semaphore then no, you don't need to bother doing that.  Pretty questionable that a "whole stack" could do it right for a single semaphore object btw.

Comment: The point of implementing `IDisposable` is to have a **determinsitc** point of release where clients can free memory at a certain time, usually when they´ve done a big amount of stuff that now gets invalid. If you don´t have (or don´t need that) it´s released at last when the app terminates.

Comment: There are many schools of thought on this.  I personally find it sloppy to have code that doesn't clean itself up and relies on the system to do it instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All OS level objects are freed up with a process termination. This is guaranteed by OS and is true for both Windows and Linux operating systems. Additionally, `IDispisable` with properly implemented dispose pattern has failsafe mechanism which ensures that unmanaged resources are reclaimed during finalization process. This process however has some limitations (in particular the finalizers are given with limited period of time they should complete). So as worst case scenario you can be sure that unmanaged resources won't outlive your process. It's of course not a best practice to leave them unattended as it can lead to resource and memory leacks in case of systematic ignoring of resource reclaiming but as exceptional case for a single resource with lifetime equivalent to application lifetime it can be acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

> I have an `IDiposable` object that lives "forever" in the application

Well if it has to live till application life time then where is the question of disposing? Rather have it freed by the run time when your application ends or recycles.

> all unmanaged resources are freed anyway when the process ends?

Yes they gets freed away once your application ends (process ends) but till then the resource sits there occupying memory (but that's what looks like your requirement is)

Comment: Well the question is that it is a recommended practice to have IDisposable for each class that has a member `IDisposable` which I want to avoid

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik If you establish that your classes do not own the `IDisposable` they are given and *should not* displose it when they exit, then it's okay if they themselves are not `IDisposable`.

Comment: @GSerg I create a semaphore using "new" inside the class itself, so they are not exactly given

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik, if that disposable item is a separate type then you don't need to.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik Then you probably should make that class `IDisposable`, but not the other classes down the chain.

Comment: "**all** unmanaged resources are freed anyway when the process ends" - technically, *it depends*; *some* unmanaged resources like database connections, transacations etc. can keep on hanging on *server side*.

Comment: Well, they should really know what to do if they miss connection since it can be any random failure on the client side anyway. It's just it will probably take some time then :)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, The sockets, which typically represent the connections, are closed with a process termination. A connection if it's a TCP connection then goes to the TIME_WAIT state which is a standard state after sending FIN packet, so in essence the path will be the same as if they are closed explicitly by application.